# loginctl doesn't show anything

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, logind

I have an headless Raspbian Jessie on a Raspberry Pi. I've set it up as read-only root to prevent SD card corruption.

When I try to use `loginctl` on it, it doesn't show any active sessions. But as I understand, it should at lease show the current SSH session I'm working on.

```
$ loginctl
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT            

0 sessions listed.
```

After trying search a lot on Google to solve this, I think that it might have something to do with systemd and/or dbus not working properly. See the output of following commands.

```
$ systemctl --user 
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused

$ pgrep -af dbus
542 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to install `libpam-systemd`.

Once I installed it and rebooted, it worked.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! I was looking all over for a solution to this problem, landed on many different posts, but nothing produced a useful result until 'loginctl no results'. I'd give you 100 points if I could :-)